# React/Redux: How to return two objects in a method that calls an API?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Here's my code snippet where I'm calling an API and returning a data object:

```
function search(location, term) {
  let body = {
   location: location,
   term: term
  };

  return callApi("search", "GET", body)
    .then(response => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
}
```

Notice how I'm returning `response.data`. I also need to return `response.extra`.

Any ideas on how to do this? Do I need to create another method?

Answer (score 1):

You can return whatever you want from the inside of a promise:

```
return callApi("search", "GET", body)
  .then(response => {
    return {
      data: response.data,
      extra: response.extra
    }
  })
```

You could, of course, return the entire response object:

```
.then(response => response)
```

to get a similar result just with more fields

Answer (score 0):

Assuming response already contains both data and extra, you can return either an array or an object (which is preferable). 
If you don't mind, you could just return response directly, or (if you want to make sure to really just expose data and extra) you return

```
{data: response.data, extra: response.extra}
```

In which case you then have to access it through the dot notation in the next promise handler.

I hope I did not misunderstand your question.